Usage of 1st and 3rd person narration in Condé's "Crossing the Mangrove"
Apart from an introductory and closing chapter, Condé's 1989 novel Crossing the Mangrove ("Traversée de la mangrove") consists of short chapters in which people from the village recount their experiences of interacting with the character who is found dead in the opening pages, Francis Sancher. Each chapter consists of the narration of one person, and is titled with that person's name. The reminiscences of twenty people are given in total, corresponding to twelve male characters and eight females.
On reading the book I noticed that the female characters speak in the first person, whereas the stories of the male characters are (generally) narrated in the third person. I assumed initially that this was a case of Condé, as a female author, giving the female characters the liberty to describe their lives in their own voice - a freedom the characters do not have in their everyday life in the village.
The pattern breaks down in two cases, however. The young boy Joby Lameaulnes, and the enigmatic vagabond Xantippe, also narrate their stories in first person. Is there some other logic that explains the choice of first or third person narration?

Françoise Pfaff, Professor of French at Howard University, made a number of interviews with Condé between 1982 and 1994. These have been collected as Conversations with Maryse Condé, available for free loan from the Internet Archive.
In the fourth interview, dated July 9 1991, Pfaff raised this very question:

FP In "Crossing the Mangrove" some chapters are in the first person
and others in the third person. Why?

Condé replied:

Some chapters came to me in the first person and others in the third.
I don't quite know why. I cannot explain it rationally. Later on, I
noticed that narratives by female characters were in the first person.
Then I realized that this was maybe more natural for me. I must have
felt more distant from characters like Loulou or Desinor the Haitian,
since their chapters are in the third person. It may depend on the
relationship between writers and characters during the writing. I
don't believe there is any given rule.

 (text bolded by me) 
So it seems that Condé did not apply a given rule consciously, but seems to have written in the first person for characters to whom she felt closer.
